# Design Automation for Revit: error when adding in adsk3LeggedToken: access token

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit-api, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

When posting a work item to design automation, I keep getting a failed to download item. When I provide the argument without adsk3LeggedToken, the file successfully downloads then starts the script. When running the script I run into an authentication issue. According to this [blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model) (see adsk3LeggedToken towards bottom), we add in the parameter into the argument and provides access. I'm using the SaveAsCloudModel() API and have run bundle succesfully in Revit API (not DA). I am using postman.

Does anyone know why I'm getting failed download error?

```
[06/19/2023 13:50:04] T:\Aces\Jobs\6c520ca0a8984a35b579ad73db46a971\zip_6.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\6c520ca0a8984a35b579ad73db46a971.
[06/19/2023 13:50:04] Warning: Zip Migration: the input of 'rvtFile' is unzipped to the correct location of 'T:\Aces\Jobs\6c520ca0a8984a35b579ad73db46a971\unpack_folder_7'.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] End download phase successfully.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\6c520ca0a8984a35b579ad73db46a971\XXXXX_JLG Revit2021 Starter File_A_detached.rvt" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\8ab7ecdf17504804c4d0b05de34b89d4.SAVE_CLOUD_MODEL.SaveModelTest8[1].package"]
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] Start script phase.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] End script phase.
[06/19/2023 13:50:05] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[06/19/2023 13:50:06] Job finished with result FailedEnvironmentSetup
[06/19/2023 13:50:06] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedDownload",
```

My work item post:

```
{
  "activityId": "SAVE_CLOUD_MODEL.SaveModelTestActivity8+current",
  "arguments": {
    "rvtFile": {
      "verb": "get",
      "url": "/* INPUT URL (TESTED AND WORKS) */",
      "pathInZip": "/* WORKING PATH */"
    },
    "result": {
      "verb": "put",
      "url": "/*OUTPUT URL (TESTED AND WORKS)*/"
    },
    "adsk3LeggedToken": "{{ouath3}}"
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I created a 2Auth Token which I thought was coming through as 3LeggedOauth. Correcting this solved the problem and was able to successfully run the automation. Thank you to those who responded.

Comment: Hi Frank, AFAIK, the job fails while calling SaveAsCloudModel() due to the reason without authorization, But after you provide adsk3LeggedToken in the workitem, the job failed at the beginning just downloading the input Revit model, right? Do you still have a workitem id we can check backend? I am talking with engineering team for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be related to your input URL. If you ask DA to download the file from OSS bucket, you need to specify the access token in the header of the `rvtFile`  argument, not `adsk3LeggedToken`.

```js
{
  "activityId": "test.myaddin+dev",
  "arguments": {
    "rvtFile": {
      "verb": "get",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/house.rvt",
      "headers":{
            "Authorization": "Bearer {{Bearer}}",
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "verb": "put",
      "url": "https://example.org/api/da/models"
    },
    "adsk3LeggedToken": "{{ouath3}}"
  }
}
```

Note. The `adsk3LeggedToken` is for accessing Revit Cloud Model API only.

Comment: Eason, thank you for responding. However, I found removing the method of using the buckets still gives me an error. I modified the AppBundle to using cloud files, ran it locally to verify then reuploaded and registered the new app bundle. What I find is, adding the adsk3LeggedToken to the argument gives me the same error in the original post.

Comment: Additionally, yes I see how the JSON I originally posted is confusing, but the URL I was accessing was public, the script runs successfully, but when I add in adsk3leggedtoken as part of the argument, the script fails, without it, the script runs and gives me the UserAuthException.

Comment: Ah... I'm sorry to hear that ... just happen to know you consulted two team members of mine for this issue. We're checking with our engineering team for insights now. Will get back to you sooner. (My apologies for the late reply. I was on business travel last week)